# How to get HttpServletRequest before controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring application and I am authenticating user in `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`'s `prehandle()` method and if user authenticated I am setting request attribute like this:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                         HttpServletResponse response, 
                         Object handler) throws Exception {  

    request.setAttribute("isAuthenticated",true);
    request.setAttribute("user",user);    
}
```

if user not authenticated I am setting like this

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                         HttpServletResponse response, 
                         Object handler) throws Exception {

    request.setAttribute("isAuthenticated",false);
    request.setAttribute("user",null);        
}
```

and then later in controller method I am retrieving user with `HttpServletRequest` like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/user", produces = "application/json")
public Object getUserByToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

    if((Boolean) request.getAttribute("isAuthenticated")) {
        return request.getAttribute("user");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(UNAUTHORIZED).body("unauthorized");       
}
```

The problem is I need to receive `HttpServletRequest` in each controller method to check if user authenticated.

What I want is that a method that is called before controller method and inside the controller class, so that I can set user in one place and get from all other controller methods

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't using spring-security and writing implementation of your own?

Comment: Can solve this problem using spring-security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a base controller this way:

```
public class BaseController {

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User getUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return (User)request.getAttribute("user");
    }
}
```

Extend all you controllers from `BaseController`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", produces = "application/json")
public Object getUserByToken(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
   // play with user object
}
```

I have shown you the example for user, similarly do for authentication flag.

Comment: also instead of returning ResponseEntity, use RestController annotation on your controller class. Instead of setting status in the body of controller method, do that using @ResponseStatus annotation on your controller method.

Comment: It does not still solve the problem I still have to give (@ModelAttribute("user") User user) in all controller methods

Comment: Can't I just catch HttpServletRequest in BaseController' method and set it and then use it my controller methods

Comment: I mean prehadler() like method in BaseController

Comment: no you need to use a interceptor. Also, the way you are doing this authentication thing is highly insecure. Stick to Spring security rather than creating your own implementations. If at all you need custom behavior, try using a custom filter in Spring security